# Knockoutjs' foreach not working when single data has returned

Tags: json, knockout.js

I have a table which is shown below. When multiple data comes, it is shown properly but if a single data come, data isn't shown in the table. I suspect absence of brackets in single data..

Multiple Data Sample:

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Tomato soup","Category":"Groceries","Price":1.39},{"Id":2,"Name":"Yo-yo","Category":"Toys","Price":3.75},{"Id":3,"Name":"Hammer","Category":"Hardware","Price":16.99}]
```

Single Data sample

```
{"Id":1,"Name":"Tomato soup","Category":"Groceries","Price":1.39}
```

Table and scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function ProductViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.productData = ko.observable();
            self.productId = ko.observable();

            self.getAllProducts = function () {
                $.get('/api/products', {}, self.productData);
            };

            self.getProductById = function () {
                $.get('/api/products/' + self.productId(), {}, self.productData);
            };
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new ProductViewModel());
    });
</script>
<input id="txtId" type="text" data-bind="value: productId" />
<button id="btnGetSpeProduct" data-bind="click: getProductById">Get Product By Id</button>
<button id="btnGetProducts" data-bind="click: getAllProducts">Get All Products</button><br />
<table data-bind="with: productData">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Category
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Price
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: Name">
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Category">
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Price">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach` binding can accept either an array or an object specifying various options. In this case, Knockout thinks the object you're giving it is the latter. It will work if you use the object syntax and specify your data using the `data` option.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: $data}">
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/Dta48/

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it has everything to do with the "absence of brackets in single data".

- The one **with brackets** means that it's an `array`; a list which can can iterate (`foreach`).
- The one **without brackets** means that it's an `object`; something which can be stored inside an array, but can not be iterated using `foreach`.

So, you want it to act like an array so you can iterate over the result. First step, you'll need to use an `observableArray` instead of observable:

```
self.productData = ko.observableArray();
```

Next, you'll need to push the data you `$.get` to that array, instead of directly binding them.

```
$.get('/api/products', function(data) {
    // Iterate over the data variable, and use
    // self.productData.push(ITEM)
    // to add it to the array
});
```

That should do it - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use observableArray instead of observable

```
self.productData = ko.observableArray();
```